# jQuery mmenu: Scroll after menu close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mmenu

in an project I do use mmenu first time. It works as expected but there is one thing I would love to have working, but it still isn't :/

Here's the URL: http://1pager.gut-entwickelt.de/

What I would love to see: After selecting an menu-point, it shouldn't scroll within milliseconds. It should wait till the menu is closed, then start scrolling.

Thatfor I added this script-part:

```
Me.mobileMenu.mmenu({
        zposition: "front",
        onClick:   {
            preventDefault: true,
            setSelected   : false
        }
    });

    Me.mobileMenu
    .find('a')
    .on(
        'click',
        function() {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            if (Me.mobileMenu.hasClass('mm-opened')) {
                Me.mobileMenu
                    .off('closed.mm')
                    .one(
                        'closed.mm',
                        function() {
                            setTimeout(
                                function(){
                                    $('html, body').animate({
                                        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
                                    });
                                }, 
                                1000
                            );

                            return false;
                        }
                    );
            } else {
                setTimeout(
                    function(){
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
                        });
                    },
                    1000
                );
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
```

This seems to work here: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples/responsive/index.html
But on that page it don't... any ideas?

Regards,
  Oliver Lippert

Comment: A timeout is not a very good solution unless that's really the only way to do something. You may want to look into whether there is a callback in mmenu to let you know that the menu is gone. In that callback you then scroll to the item.

Comment: May this is also a good thing, but currently not my real problem. I seek an option to stop the auto-scroll from mmenu or whatever. After I found what option to set or what event to prevent, I con do some fine-tuning with the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "closed" event is triggered when the menu finished closing, so you shouldn't need an extra timeout.
Have a look at this example, it's a bit more straightforward:
http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/demo/onepage.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now it works. But may you can have another look, the animation is different to your linked website. Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Extended to Fred's reply I had another JS-code for doing the scroll. After disabling it, now the menu closes first, and the Scroll starts later.